# How to use browser's fonts with mapbox?

Tags: fonts, mapbox-gl-js

I'm builing a POC with last Mapbox's version.

From the same source I have two layers, one to show points, and the other one to print an hello world for each points :

```
layerPoint : {
    id : this.layerPointId,
    type : "circle",
    source : this.sourceId,
    paint : {
        "circle-color" : this.color,
        "circle-radius" : 4
    }
}
layerText : {
    id : this.layerTextId,
    type : "symbol",
    source : this.sourceId,
    layout : {
        "text-field" : "Hello world",
        "text-size": 12
    }
}
```

I got an error on my console:

```
layers.l.text.uuid12987456.layout.text-field: use of "text-field" requires a style "glyphs" property
```

So I look [into Mapbox's doc](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#glyphs) to see that I should add a glyph property if I need text-fiel. But what glyph property should I use if I want to got defaults browser or OS fonts? I don't need any icons and my POC must run on a disconnected environment.

Answer (score 2):

Since for text rendering mapbox-gl-js use fonts in PBF format, for offline mode you need to have a local copy of the fonts. You can see a ready-made example: [klokantech/mapbox-gl-js-offline-example](https://github.com/klokantech/mapbox-gl-js-offline-example).

Or you can use [HTML-marker](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api#marker):

```
// add markers to map
geojson.features.forEach(function(marker) {
    // create a DOM element for the marker
    var el = document.createElement('div');
    el.innerHTML = marker.properties.message
    el.className = 'marker';
    el.addEventListener('click', function() {
      window.alert(marker.properties.message);
    });

    // add marker to map
    new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
      .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
      .addTo(map);
});
```

[ https://jsfiddle.net/3kzbs7nn/ ]